# Is it possible to setup a private TFS checkin policy?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, checkin-policy

As I understand the checkin-policy are set on the server, but enforced on the client.
Since they are enforced on the client, is there a way to setup a private checkin policy.

I want to have a checkin policy for myself, but I can't set it on the TFS server as that would force everyone to follow that policy as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is not possible.  If you're creating custom check-in policies you could have it filter by user, but you'd still have to turn it on at the server level and have every user install it locally.

Comment: Any chance this has changed in TFS2013? I need this as well, and it seems like a pretty basic thing. I can't even **test** my policy, because adding it to my project does so for the rest of the team.

Comment: This hasn't changed, but if you want to test it just create a testing Team Project so you don't affect others.

Comment: In order to test a policy, you have to create a whole new project? That seems like a hassle, especially since it's version control, and that project **can't ever be deleted**.

Comment: Team Projects can be deleted.